# What is the difference between these arrow functions

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

```
const post = text => (
   ....
)
```

and

```
const post = text => {
    ....
}
```

I'm new, sorry if this a stupid question,
I've searched some articles, but didn't get it.
Could someone help to explain

Comment: fn => expression, fn => statement-block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const post = text => (
   ....
)
```

This arrow function expects an expression or single statement in parentheses. The result of expression will be returned when you call the function. No need to write `return` explicitly.

example:

```
const isOdd = num => ( num % 2 == 1 );
```

---

The second arrow function expects a function body. If you don't explicitly return, `undefined` will be returned.

```
const post = text => {
    ....
}
```

example:

```
const isOdd = num =>{
   return num % 2 == 1;
}
```

---

In the first form you don't always need `()` around expression, but it is required when when you return an object literal.

```
const Point = (x,y) => {x,y};
console.log(Point(0,0)); //undefined
```

```
const Point = (x,y) => ({x,y});
console.log(Point(0,0)); //{ x: 1, y: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

first arrow function means return a value `(what is return)`
second arrow function means your function that you wants to define `{define your function}`
for more description follow this sample:

```js
const post = text => (text) // return text

const post2 = text =>{ //define your function
  return (text)
}

console.log(post("hello post"));
console.log(post("hello post2"));
```